# Find all real values $a$ and $b$ such that $a+ib=i^{i^{i}}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Find all real values $a$ and $b$ such that  $a+ib=i^{i^{i}}$ ?

My Try :

using the fact that $z^w=e^{w \log z}$, First I compute $i^i$ 
$$i^i=e^{i \log i}= e^{i (\log |i| + i arg (i))}=e^{- \frac{\pi}{2} - 2k \pi} \ \ \ \ k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Now

$$i^{i^{i}} = \left( e^{- \frac{\pi}{2} - 2k \pi} \right)^i = e^{i (\log |e^{- \frac{\pi}{2} - 2k \pi}| + i arg (e^{- \frac{\pi}{2} - 2k \pi}))} =  e^{i (\log |e^{- \frac{\pi}{2} - 2k \pi}| + i 2m\pi )} 
= e^{ (- \frac{\pi}{2} i - 2k \pi i - 2m\pi )} = -i e^{-2m\pi} $$

$m \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Therefore $a=0$ and $b=-e^{-2m\pi} $

Because We raised to $i$ two times I thought I might end up with two arbitrary factors $m$ and $k$, but one of them has to disappear. Is my solution correct ? Can we possibly have more than one arbitrary factor in the final result ?

Thanks.

Comment: Exponentiation is not associative:  $a^{(b^c)} \ne (a^b)^c$ in general, so $a^{b^c}$ can only mean one or the other.  It turns out that $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$ already, so the convention is that $a^{b^c} = a^{(b^c)}$.

Comment: @Roozbeh-unity : there's no really good way to define $i^i$, let alone $i^{i^i}$.

Comment: @StefanSmith : That's what I am worrying about, what is the "definition" ? What is the problem with what I did ? I used the very fundamental rule $z^w=e^{w \log z}$ and moved on ...

Comment: @Roozbeh-unity : From your answer, "$\log$" and "$arg$" appear to be multi-valued functions, so if you compute $i^{i^i}$ using your definition of $z^w$, it seems to me that you should _expect_ that there should be at least two arbitrary factors in your final result.  I'm not saying you're definition of $z^w$ is wrong, but, as you know, you cannot define $z^w$ in such a way that the familiar rules of exponentiation and multiplication that we use with real numbers always work.  The result is that even good mathematicians argue about the value(s) of $z^w$ for complex $z$ and $w$.

Comment: @Roozbeh-unity : why are you trying to find $i^{i^i}$ in the first place?

Comment: @Roozbeh-unity : also, the universal mathematical convention (and no good mathematicians will disagree with me here) is that $x^{x^x}$ means $x^{(x^x)}$, not $({x^x})^x$.  If you mean $({i^i})^i$, which it seems you do, you need the parentheses.

Comment: @StefanSmith It has appeared on a qualifying exam , That's why I am trying to solve it. Thanks for your comments ! Without parentheses it can be interpreted differently as you see the diversity in people's ideas.

Comment: @Roozbeh-unity : I would not put this on a qualifying exam unless I knew everyone taking it had been taught the same convention for what "$z^w$" means, or if it were simply provided on the exam.  I don't think there really is a universal convention for it, or even for whether it is a multi-valued "function" or has a single value (presumably using the "principle branch" of the complex logarithm that people usually use).  I don't think there is even a standard definition for $\sqrt{z}$ for complex $z$ (is it double-valued?  single-valued?

Comment: ...if it is single-valued, which value do you pick?  What makes that value better than the other one?  Please note that at least in Andres's answer, he felt compelled to explain what convention he was using.  Although he called it the "standard convention", and it is the most common convention, the fact that he bothered to explain it all shows that it is not universally taken for granted, the way, for example, $\sqrt{4} = 2$ and not $-2$ is.

Answer (score 4):

Your first step is good, but
$$i^{i^i}=i^{(i^i)}$$
so you second step should be the other way around.
$$(i^i)^i=i^{i\cdot i}=i^{-1}=-i$$
(This is **not** the final result; it's just an example of the calculation of the value of the other (wrong) way of interpretation.)

Comment: I looked at it this way $((i^i))^i$, Do you think the order changes the final result ?

Comment: If that is what you meant, it's ok, but when $a^{b^c}$ appears in a text, you should first evaluate the uppermost power.

Comment: As you can see from the last line of my answer, the result, in that case, is just $-i$.

Comment: This is not correct. The answer of Andres is the right approach.

Comment: @drhab, You're right, but I was only pointing out that the OPs try was wrong.

Comment: Oh, I overlooked that. Now I understand the upvotes :-).

Comment: @Ragnar: Perhaps this should be mentioned in your answer as it is not clear that $-i$ is not the correct solution until one reads the comments.

Answer (score 3):

$i=e^{i\pi/2}$, so $\displaystyle i^i=(e^{i\pi/2})^i=e^{-\pi/2}$ and $$i^{i^i}=i^{(i^i)}=(e^{i\pi/2})^{e^{-\pi/2}}=e^{i\left(\frac\pi2 e^{-\pi/2}\right)}=\cos\left(\frac\pi2 e^{-\pi/2}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac\pi2 e^{-\pi/2}\right).$$

As pointed out in the comments, I should probably make an assumption explicit: I am using the standard convention that writes $\alpha\ne0$ as $|\alpha|e^{i\theta}$ for some $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi]$ when evaluating $\alpha^\beta$. Without an explicit description of what is meant by $\alpha^\beta$ or, if we do not follow the convention, we can end up with different answers, since $i=e^{i5\pi/2}=e^{-3\pi/2}=\dots$, and different choices here lead to different  values of $i^{e^{-\pi/2}}$.

I see the question has changed and now asks for all possible values of the expression: $i=e^{i(4a+1)\pi/2}$ for some integer $a$, so $i^i$ can be any number of the form $e^{-(4a+1)\pi/2}=e^{(4b-1)\pi/2}$ for some integer $b$. Finally, $\displaystyle i^{i^i}$ could be any number of the form $$\cos\left((4c+1)\frac\pi2e^{(4b-1)\pi/2}\right)+i\sin\left((4c+1)\frac\pi2e^{(4b-1)\pi/2}\right)$$ for any integers $b,c$.

Comment: I think your answer has a problem, if you see $i=e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2k \pi) }$ , you would get $e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}-2k \pi}$
Therefore you are losing some values.

Comment: I am treating exponential as a function, rather than as a multivalued function. This is the standard convention: Write $\alpha\ne0$ as $|\alpha|e^{i\theta}$ for some $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$ when evaluating $\alpha^\beta$. I agree that without an explicit description of what is meant, or if we do not follow the convention, we can end up with different answers.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo : You really can't do that. You must have in mind several values, because now you have made the simple power function discontinuous at every point on the positive reals (!). It's worthless in that case.

Comment: These computational subtleties are why complex analysis is never as easy as it looks.

Comment: Ah, silly me. I should have cut at $\theta=\pi$.  I'll edit later, once I find a second.

Comment: @StefanSmith I agree with you on the convention, the $[0,2\pi)$ was a typo. I fixed it a few hours ago, though.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo : I read MPW's solution, and the question seems to have a good answer that does not depend on how branch cuts are made if you are willing to pay the price of multi-valued answer.  I prefer this approach, since it is not obvious to me that any branch cut must be the best.  It looks like you did the same at the end of your answer.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo : the end of your answer may be bugged: do you mean "$i=e^{i(4a+1)/2}$"?

Comment: @StefanSmith So many typos... Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think any one of these answers is complete. First, it is universally understood that $i^{i^i}$ means only $i^{(i^i)}$ and *never* $(i^i)^i$. So we must first find all values $v$ of $i^i$, then find all values of $i^v$.

We compute $v = i^i = (e^{\pi i/2+2\pi ik})^i = e^{-\pi/2-2\pi k}$ for each integer $k$ (there are multiple values for this expression). Note these are all real numbers.

For each of these, we compute $i^v = (e^{\pi i/2+2\pi im})^v =
(e^{\pi i/2+2\pi im})^{e^{-\pi/2-2\pi k}} = e^{i\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}(4m+1)e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}(4k+1)}}$ for all integers $k$ and $m$. These can be written as $\cos \theta_{mk} + i \sin \theta_{mk}$, where $\theta_{mk} = \frac{\pi}{2}(4m+1)e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}(4k+1)}$.

I hope I don't have a typo in all of that. It's a doubly indexed family of points on the unit circle.

Comment: Found a minor typo, but didn't affect correctness of final answer. Fixed in answer now.

Comment: although in general I think it's a dubious idea to raise a complex number to the power of another complex number, for reasons you can guess, I can't find anything wrong with your answer, so I upvoted it.  It seems the answer must be multi-valued, or else you favor one version of the complex logarithm over another with no good reason.

Comment: @StefanSmith: Thanks for the upvote. One can only define $z^w$ as $e^{w\log z}$, and that's precisely where the multiple-valuedness comes in--the imaginary part of $\log z$ has a countable number of distinct values, all differing by integral multiples of $2\pi$, owing to the $2\pi i$-periodicity of the exponential function. This happens each time you apply $\log(\cdot)$, and you have to apply it twice in this problem because there are two successive exponentiations to compute.

Answer (score 1):

$i^{i}=e^{-\frac{1}{2}\pi+k2\pi}$ is correct.

Then:

$i^{i^{i}}=i^{e^{-\frac{1}{2}\pi+k2\pi}}=e^{\left(e^{-\frac{1}{2}\pi+k2\pi}\right)\ln i}=e^{\left(e^{-\frac{1}{2}\pi+k2\pi}\right)i\left(\frac{1}{2}\pi+m2\pi\right)}$

This results in:

$i^{i^{i}}=e^{i\left(\frac{1}{2}\pi+m2\pi\right)\left(e^{-\frac{1}{2}\pi+k2\pi}\right)}=\cos\left[\left(\frac{1}{2}\pi+m2\pi\right)\left(e^{-\frac{1}{2}\pi+k2\pi}\right)\right]+i\sin\left[\left(\frac{1}{2}\pi+m2\pi\right)\left(e^{-\frac{1}{2}\pi+k2\pi}\right)\right]$

Here $k$ and $m$ are integers.

Comment: Actually we should find all the real values $a$ and $b$ such that $a+ib=i^{i^{i}}$, so I guess we should not take particular m and k. Sorry for that, I will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

If $\alpha \not = 0$ then define $\alpha^{\beta} = e^{\beta \log \alpha} $. But to define $\log \alpha$ there is ambiguity in how we choose to define a logarithm. We can define the principal logarithm by $\log \alpha = \log |\alpha| + i\arg \alpha$ where $\alpha \in (-\pi,\pi]$. Thus, all other possible logarithms are given by $\log \alpha = \log |\alpha| + i\arg \alpha + 2\pi i n$.

Now $\log i = \log |i| + i\arg i + 2\pi i n = \pi i + 2\pi i n = \pi i (2n+1)$. Thus, 
$$ i^i = e^{i\log i} = e^{-\pi(2n+1)} $$ 
Thus, 
$$i^{i^i} = e^{e^{-\pi(2n+1)}\log i} = e^{e^{-\pi(2n+1)}\pi i (2m+1)} = \cos \left( e^{-\pi(2n+1)}\pi(2m+1)\right) + i \sin\left( e^{-\pi(2n+1)}\pi(2m+1)\right)   $$

My answer differs from what some people wrote above, I am too lazy to check the small details, just rather to show you the idea of one way of doing these problems.

Note: I am not a fan of using the exponent multiplication rule $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$ involving complex numbers. Because it is not true. Of course, here we are considering all possible exponents so it is safe to use it but in general it is not true and can lead to mistakes if one is not careful with it.